# Using datatables/webmethods in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been geting some viewstatemac errors when implementing jQuery and JSON recently, in a webforms app.  I'm not using a server farm, etc etc - so I'm assuming that viewstate is somehow causing the issue - so rather than diagnose the problem (which I've tried to do for several weeks), I want to move to MVC to remove viewstate altogether - which should mean no more viewstate errors (hopefully).

So far so good - I have my screen rendering in a view, from a model in MVC.  Where I'm uncertain now, is in my jQuery, where I had the following code:

```
 //function to show grid
function getGrid() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "courses.aspx/getGrid",
        data: "{tbDatet:'" + $("#tbDate").val() + "',ddlDayst:'" + getDays() + "',ddlTypet:'" + $("#ddlType").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg2) {
            $("#jGrid").html(msg2.d);
            hideWait();
            addJQGrid();
            },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            hideWait();
            sendErr(errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

Where my jSon goes to:

url: "courses.aspx/getGrid"

...how do I replace that within MVC?

It currently goes to:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getGrid(ByVal tbDatet As String, ByVal ddlDayst As Integer, ByVal ddlTypet As Integer) As String
    Dim c As New course
    Dim id As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id")
    Return c.getCourseArray(tbDatet, ddlDayst, ddlTypet)
End Function
```

The getCourseArray function simply queries the database (using dataadapters and datatables, and also the session object).  I have two queries:

1) Can I keep the getGrid function and code exactly as it is above, but have it within an MVC file?

2) Once I have it in an MVC type file, can I still query my backend database using traditional dataadapters and datatables and session values (as per webforms VS)?

Thank you for any pointers/guidance,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

First if you are going to be doing asp.net MVC you do not need a WebMethod, and there is no Viewstate.

The first problem you are having is in MVC you don't need to add the .aspx to the file in the URL, the route handles that, here is a blog post that show you how to get this to work http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2010/12/easy-ajax-with-aspnet-mvc-and-jquery.html

also for doing the partial view, take a look at this post http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2011/11/more-ajax-with-mvc-using-partial-views.html

Comment: Hi - thanks Bob - I know there is no viewstate (which is good - I think that's what's causing some issues I'm seeing).

Comment: (sorry pressed enter) - so I need a controller and a view - the controller could do the normal queries as I had already done previously in my code-behind, and then create a return value (which in this case would be an HTML string of markup), which the controller can then pass to the View to return?  Sorry if I seem a little bemused, I'm trying to learn as I go along.  Thanks again Bob,  Mark

Comment: you don't create a string in the controller, you pass the values in to a model then pass that to the view, see the second blog post URL

Comment: Hi - thanks again - my problem is I need to have quite a bit of code to "create" a grid, which contains popups, dates, rooms etc - all of which was done previously, by creating a table as a string, and returning the string to the ajax call from my javascript.  Just have figure out how to do some normal programming to create the string html now!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7.*

```
  <system.webServer>
  ...
  <tracing>
  <traceFailedRequests>
    <add path="*">
      <traceAreas>
        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
      </traceAreas>
      <failureDefinitions statusCodes="401.3-999,405" verbosity="Error" />
    </add>
  </traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
...
</system.webServer>
```